# Can I disable "debug view" in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugview

Visual Studio 2010 switches to "debug view" when i click 'start debugging' - much like Eclipse does.
Can i disable this feature - if so how?

My machine doesn't perform very well - therefore the feature is irritating.
Besides with two monitors i don't need it.

Ctrl-F5 starts without debugging.
That's not what I meant, I would like to debug without the "debug view", i.e. without changing the layout of all windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the layout of the windows in debug mode, but unfortunately, you cannot turn off the transition from "coding mode" to "debug mode".  Your layout is persisted between debugging sessions, though, so any changes you make will remain.

Answer (score -2):

Just click on Debug/Start without debugging from the menu or Ctrl-F5.

Answer (score -3):

Just Press Control-F5